# How to reload Fragment after removing an item in list view by clicking on delete button in item whose code in adaptor class?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

I have a following code in my adaptor class

```
firestoredb.collection("medicinedata").document(user.getPhoneNumber()).collection("medicineSchedule").document(v.getTag().toString()).delete()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Medicine delete successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
```

after successful delete from database the item still show in listview until i go to another fragment and came back. give me solution what to do to reload or refresh the fragment aftert successfull delete of my item

Comment: you don't have to reload the fragment and you don't _actually_ have to change anything to your listview/recyclerview, because they are managed by an adapter, so you need to tell the _adapter_ that stuff has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are to remove data in the list if addOnSuccessListener run and refresh your adapter class data. To refresh the adapter then use this code in the addOnSuccessListener method after removing data

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```